# Using Selenium WebDriver, Protractor with Scalatest in an SBT project

Tags: webdriver, sbt, protractor, scalatest

Our project setup is as following:

1. We are using 'Play framework' and SBT as a build tool.
2. We have Jenkins for continuous delivery
3. We are using Scalatest for writing Selenium tests
4. Additionally we have Sonarqube for consolidating test results.
5. For Frontend we are using AngularJS for dynamic content.

We wanted to use **Protractor** as it can access AngularJS specific elements, but installing it locally is not what we want. Instead we want to have a dependency listed in Build.scala file and somehow we should be able to write Protractor code in Scalatest. How to go about it?